# which approach (below mentioned) should be used in pl/sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, filter

I have a stored procedure in which a temporary table is created.

There are 16 different select statements which are used to insert data into temp table by using joins on 4 tables at a time.

New requirement is to apply few more where conditions based on some input parameters.

My questions is:

I have two choices now:

1. apply conditions in where clause in each select statements while inserting data into temporary table.
2. do not apply any condition while inserting the data but in the end delete the data from temp table (data which is not required).

The second approach seems simple, but I was thinking about performance issues as initially unnecessary data would be inserted into it, but again there are multiple filters applied every time.

Can anyone guide me which approach should be used.

Basically among filtering, insertion, deletion which takes more time.

All tables have thousands of rows in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer without the exact details, but generally speaking, the first approach sounds better.

The second approach means you'll be doing (potentially, depends on the exact conditions) twice the I/O - once to copy the data into the temp table, and again to delete it. If your dataset is large, this will be considerable.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is better.

If the select is taking time, you should optimize the selects so that it use the indexes.

Secondly,you have a large table and then you are selecting a handful of records from it, doesn't solve your problem.